# how group id can be used in Sarama

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

As you probably know, Sarama's documentation is so bad. Nothing is clear. I have just found this example: https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama#example-Consumer

It consumes the messages. That's ok. I couldn't figure out how to use GroupID while consuming.

How can set group id in Sarama?

Answer (score 1):

By default Sarama does not support Consumer Groups.

As mentioned in [Sarama's FAQ](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-can-i-use-sarama-to-monitor-or-join-a-consumer-group), support for Consumer Groups is provided by a separate plugin: https://github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster